# how to manage pass value set by dialog box in VB form application to its caller

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form Main that calls open a dialog, which gets a text value response and that value would need to be used in Main. I was wondering how to achieve this where Main would have access to this after the dialog closes. The minimal example of this is as follows:

```
Private Class Main
    Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenDialog.Click
        Dim dialog As New Dialog
        dialog.Show()

    End Sub
End Class
```

and Dialog

```
Private Class Dialog
    Private response As String
    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        response = txtResponse.Text
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: At the most simple form, simply change Private response As String to Public response as String.  But I would suggest you need to do a lot more reading on access modifiers before getting too far into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide a pass-through property for the `Text` of the `TextBox`:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Response As String
    Get
        Return txtResponse.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

It's hard to know for certain but you probably out to be displaying the form as a modal dialogue:

```vb
Dim response As String = Nothing

Using dlg As New Dialog
    If dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        response = dlg.Response
    End If
End Using

'...
```

Now you don't need a `Click` event handler for your `Button` as you can just set its `DialogResult` property to `OK` in the designer.

Comment: this sounds great! I was wondering how I might be able to modify this where some database operations and file creation occurs on clicking ok.  Or if that's the case, will I need to hold onto the ok button click handler?  If so, will this also potentially create a race condition?

Comment: @reactor Sounds like a new question to me.

Answer (score -1):

In that case the simple solution could be the following:

```
Private Class Main
    Private Sub btnOpenDialog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenDialog.Click
        Dim AskDialog As New Dialog
        Dim Response As String
        Response = AskDialog.DialogShow()
    End Sub
End Class
```

and Dialog

```
Public Class Dialog
    Private response As String
    Public Function DialogShow() As String
        Me.ShowDialog()
        Return response
    End Function

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        response = txtResponse.Text
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```